# Bash Alias Help

Tags: bash, unix, permissions, alias

I am writing 4 aliases for a project and currently two of them are working. The e and ll alias work but the cx alias gives me an error cx: command not found. also, my rm alias just removes the file specified but does not give any sort of confirmation.

Here is what I am looking for from these two aliases..

1. an alias named "cx" which accepts one or more files/directories
   and adds the execute permission on the specified files/directories.
2. an alias called "rm" that will display a confirmation message each time you remove a file.

here are my aliases...

```
alias e="exit"
alias ll="ls $1 -l"
alias cx="chmod a+x $1"
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to use passed in parameters, you don't want an alias, you want a function

```
cx(){ chmod a+x $1; }
ll(){ ls $1 -l; }
```

In these particular cases, you can do without the positional parameters altogether because the parameter is at the very end and aliases are essentially inline replaced with their definition.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
alias cx='chmod a+x'
```

So `cx ./foo` is now `chmod a+x ./foo` and `ll ./foo` is now `ls -l ./foo`

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ touch foo && ls -l ./foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 siegex siegex 0 Mar  7 12:14 ./foo
$ alias cx='chmod a+x'
$ alias ll='ls -l'
$ cx ./foo
$ ll ./foo
-rwxrwxr-x 1 siegex siegex 0 Mar  7 12:14 ./foo
```

Comment: the assignment is to use aliases. i tried this without the parameter and am still getting cx: command not found.

Comment: @bluetickk then you are doing something wrong, see my 'Proof of Concept'

Comment: alias cx='chmod a+x" is my alias.

when invoked i still get cx: command not found.

also, alias rm='rm -i' still does not give me a confirmation

Comment: @bluetickk `cx='chmod a+x"` I'm not sure if that is a typo, but you are mixing single quotes with double quotes which you can't do.  Either use only single quotes or use only double quotes to surround your alias.

Comment: @bluetickk then 1) Are you *sure* you are using `bash` as your shell? 2) If so, then after you type `alias cx='chmod a+x'` you should be able to type just `alias cx` and it should confirm that it is set to `chmod a+x`. Report back with results

Comment: @bluetickk another thing, you're not trying to define your aliases on the command line then running a shell script that tries to use them are you?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 10.10 currently so i am 99% sure that I am using bash. For this assignment we are writing these 4 aliases in a .txt file to run. I tried creating an alias from the command line just as you did, and it did confirm that cx is set to alias cx='chmod a+x' . but when i ran cx i got this error : missing operand after a+x

Comment: @bluetickk as typed, the *missing operand* error is expected, note that is very much different than *command not found* error.  Typing `cx` by itself is the same as typing `chmod a+x` by itself on the command line which makes it more obvious why it says you are missing an operand, i.e. the file to change the mode of.  Typing `cx /path/to/some/file` should work as expected

Comment: Ok so creating the alias from the command line works correctly. but when i run the exact same alias in a text file, i get the command not found error. I am confused because some of the aliases work and this one and the remove file doesnt?

Comment: @bluetickk as for the *.txt* file that you are putting these in to run.  Assuming you are putting `#!/bin/bash` at the top of that *.txt* file and running it, that only sets those aliases for that *instance* of the non-interactive shell you just invoked by running that script.  Those aliases *do NOT* affect the parent shell running which is the one you are using to type things at the command line.  If you want aliases to affect your current shell, you need to put them in your ~/.bashrc file which affects any shell called by your user. If you want to make them global they go in `/etc/profile`

Comment: The only thing in the text file are the alias definitions. Could this be the problem? We are to run the text file and then perform some tasks which we are recording with a script.

Comment: @bluetick: what are you typing to run this text file?

Comment: ./myaliases - myaliases.txt is the filename in my home directory

Comment: @bluetick: I'll assume `./myaliases.txt` is `chmod +x`. In either case, you should put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of that script to guarantee `bash` is used as the interpreter.   The other "tasks" you want to do should ALSO be in that same file because that is the only file which those aliases are defined.  You could however do a `source ./myaliases` as the first line in the other script which you are doing your other tasks. This tells that script to read in './myaliases' and use whatever it defines in the current script.

Comment: I am so sorry SiegeX, you taught me a lot in the past 15 minutes but I solved my own stupid mistake. I am assuming that a '. ./myaliases' is the equivalent of 'source ./myaliases' I think that I must have missed the first '.' before when running the .txt. Here is the line in the assignment in which it says to run the .txt "run: . ./myaliases"

Comment: @bluetickk yes, `source ./myaliases` is identical to `. ./myaliases` but a bit more explicit.  See `help source` and `help .`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should be better :)

```
alias e='exit'
alias ll='ls $1 -l'
alias cx='chmod a+x $1'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

The magic is ' instead of "

Comment: aliases should not contain positional parameters

Comment: i am still getting cx: command not found when i invoke cx. im also not getting a confirmation when i invoke rm.

Comment: The ' insead of " helps to consider the $1, which is useless here... I think that the usage is the key here. You shoud load these alises using the source command

Comment: I'll assume the above comment was to me.  How do you set `$1` outside of a function?

Answer (score 0):

The command `shopt -s expand_aliases` will allow alias expansion in non-interactive Bash shells.  (It's not needed at the command line, since that would be an interactive shell.)

If you're testing your aliases in a script, that's probably part of your problem.
Try adding the `shopt`command to your script before attempting to run any aliased commands.